# How do I fix this compile error: "Expected: Expression"

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

When a user updates the status of an individual case, that change needs to be stamped across all cases under the account number. Within the VB, I am trying to use the following SQL to update the table with the information the user has put into the form.

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Main Details] " & _

"SET [Main Details].[Status] = '" & Status & "' " & _

"AND [Main Details].[On Hold] = '" & On Hold & "' " & _

"WHERE   [Main Details].[Account] = '" & Account & "';"
```

However, I am getting a compilation error, and I suspect it is something to do with "On Hold". How can I correct this? Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

For context, I am looking at a combo box called "ReportSelection" on a form called "Main Details". Within the "After Update" event procedure, there is the following code:

```vb
Private Sub
 ReportSelection_AfterUpdate()

     If ReportSelection = "Enforcement Letter" Or ReportSelection = "Fees
 Letter" Or ReportSelection = "Follow
 On Letter" Or ReportSelection =
 "Reminder Letter BO" Or
 ReportSelection = "Reminder Letter CR"
 Or ReportSelection = "Reminder Letter
 CT" Or ReportSelection = "Reminder
 Letter NNDR" Or ReportSelection =
 "Reminder Letter RTD" Or
 ReportSelection = "Reminder Letter SD"
 Then
                 CmbStatus = "HOLD Until"
                 [On Hold] = Date + 5
             End If

     DoCmd.RunSQL "UPDATE [Main Details] " & _
       "SET [Main Details].[Status] = '" & Status & "' " & _
       "AND [Main Details].[On Hold] = '" & On Hold & "' " & _
       "WHERE   [Main Details].[Account] = '" & Account &
 "';"

     DoCmd.DoMenuItem acFormBar, acRecordsMenu, acSaveRecord, ,
 acMenuVer70

     Select Case Me!ReportSelection

     Case "Write Email"

         DoCmd.OpenForm "CaseEmail", acNormal, , , acFormEdit,
 acWindowNormal

         Exit Sub

     Case "Arrangement Letter"

         Set dbs = CurrentDb

        DoCmd.RunSQL "SELECT * FROM [Arrangements] " & _
             "WHERE [Client]  = '" & Me!Client & "' " & _
             "AND   [Account] = '" & Me!Account & "' " & _
             "AND   [Status]  = 'Made';"

         Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(SQL)

         On Error GoTo ArrangementNotFound

         rst.MoveFirst

         ' rst!PaymentCode

         rst.Close
         Set dbs = Nothing

         GoTo RunReport
          ArrangementNotFound:

         rst.Close
         Set dbs = Nothing

         MsgBox "No arrangement has been made for this account"

         Exit Sub

     Case "Reminder Letter", _
         "Reminder Letter BO", _
         "Reminder Letter CR", _
         "Reminder Letter CT", _
         "Reminder Letter NNDR", _
         "Reminder Letter RTD", _
         "Reminder Letter SD", _
         "Enforcement Letter", "Commital Letter"

         If [Status] = "HOLD" Then
             MsgBox "Order is on HOLD", vbExclamation
             Exit Sub
         End If

         If Me![Bailiff Name] <> "" Then
             MsgBox "Order is with " & Me![Bailiff Name], vbExclamation
             Exit Sub
         End If

         If [First Letter] <> 0 Then
             GoTo RunReport
         Else
             MsgBox "Order has not yet been 1st Noticed", vbExclamation
             Exit Sub
         End If

     End Select
      RunReport:

     Select Case Me!ReportSelection

     Case "Details - Account", "Nulla Bona - All Cases", "Arrangement
 Letter"

         WhereCondition = "[Client]='" & Me!Client & "' AND [Account]='" &
 Me!Account & "'"

     Case Else

         WhereCondition = "[Reference]=" & Forms![Main
 Details]!Reference

     End Select

     On Error GoTo InvalidReport

     DoCmd.OpenReport Me![ReportSelection], acViewPreview, ,
 WhereCondition, acWindowNormal

     Select Case Me!ReportSelection

     Case "Council Tax Seizure"

         '*** DO NOTHING ***

     Case "Details"

         If Me!Return Then

             Sleep 1000

             SendKeys "%(fp)v{ENTER}Z:\Returns\" & Me!Client
 & "\" & Trim(Me!Account) & "_" &
 Trim(Me!Summons) & ".pdf{ENTER}", True

             Sleep 500

             DoCmd.Close acReport, Me!ReportSelection, acSaveNo

         End If

     Case "Details - Account"

         If Me!Return Then

             Sleep 1000

             SendKeys "%(fp)v{ENTER}Z:\Returns\" & Me!Client
 & "\" & Trim(Me!Account) &
 ".pdf{ENTER}", True

             Sleep 500

             DoCmd.Close acReport, Me!ReportSelection, acSaveNo

         End If

     Case "Nulla Bona"

         If Me!Return Then

             Sleep 1000

             SendKeys "%(fp)v{ENTER}Z:\Returns\" & Me!Client
 & "\" & Trim(Me!Account) & "_" &
 Trim(Me!Summons) & "NB.pdf{ENTER}",
 True

             Sleep 500

             DoCmd.Close acReport, Me!ReportSelection, acSaveNo

         End If

         DoCmd.OpenReport "Details", acViewPreview, , "[Reference]=" &
 Forms![Main Details]!Reference,
 acWindowNormal

         If Me!Return Then

             Sleep 1000

             SendKeys "%(fp)v{ENTER}Z:\Returns\" & Me!Client
 & "\" & Trim(Me!Account) & "_" &
 Trim(Me!Summons) & ".pdf{ENTER}", True

             Sleep 500

             DoCmd.Close acReport, "Details", acSaveNo

         End If

     Case "Nulla Bona - All Cases"

         If Me!Return Then

             Sleep 1000

             SendKeys "%(fp)v{ENTER}Z:\Returns\" & Me!Client
 & "\" & Trim(Me!Account) &
 "NB.pdf{ENTER}", True

             Sleep 500

             DoCmd.Close acReport, Me!ReportSelection, acSaveNo

         End If

         DoCmd.OpenReport "Details - Account", acViewPreview, ,
 "[Client]='" & Me!Client & "' AND
 [Account]='" & Me!Account & "'",
 acWindowNormal

         If Me!Return Then

             Sleep 1000

             SendKeys "%(fp)v{ENTER}Z:\Returns\" & Me!Client
 & "\" & Trim(Me!Account) &
 ".pdf{ENTER}", True

             Sleep 500

             DoCmd.Close acReport, "Details - Account", acSaveNo

         End If

     Case Else

         '------------------------------------------+
         ' STAMP EACH CASE WITH TYPE OF LETTER SENT |
         '------------------------------------------+

         Set con = Application.CurrentProject.Connection

         SQL = "INSERT INTO [Free Type] ( Reference, [Text], Username ) " & _
             "SELECT DISTINCTROW Reference, '" & _
             ReportSelection & " Sent', '" & _
             [Forms]![Current User]![Initials] & "' " & _
             "FROM [Main Details] " & _
             "WHERE Client  = '" & [Forms]![Main Details]![Client] & "' "
 & _
             "AND   Account = '" & [Forms]![Main Details]![Account] &
 "';"

         con.Execute SQL

     End Select

     Exit Sub

 InvalidReport:

     MsgBox "This report is currently unavailable, please try again later."

End Sub
```

Also, it is worth mentioning that a similar piece of code works for a different combo box, without any kind of relevant declarations in the code.

Apologies for not providing much context before, this is my first foray into VB, SQL and Access.

Comment: Do you have the variable `On Hold` literally that way in your code ? I don't think that visual basic allow spaces in it's variable names.

Comment: Yes, I do. `On Hold` is the name of the field. I have tried using `Me![On Hold]` also, but it does not work. Tf the name of the field is formatted this way, is there anything I can do if vb does not allow it?

Comment: There is no VB variable declared in your code called "On Hold".  This may be possible in Access, but it's NOT possible in VB.  Post your VB variable declarations and I'm sure someone can help you fix your code.

Comment: `Dim Client_Save, Type_Save, Response As String
Dim Received_Save As Long
Dim OriginalDue As Double
Dim con As Object
Dim SQL, WhereCondition, BailiffNameSave As String
Dim dbs As Database, rst, rstFLA As Recordset` 

These are the declarations. Thanks.

Comment: Edit your post and add the entire block of code with full context.  You are not providing enough information for anyone to help you.  For example, I don't see variables for Status or Account which your original post seems to indicate exist.

Comment: I have editted my original post. Thank you for your time.

Comment: In addition to the answer by mwolfe02, there's something else in _dire_ need of being fixed ASAP: Your declarations aren't doing what you probably think they are. VB(A) requires the type to be given for _each_ variable in a grouped declaration, and silently assigns the Variant type to any that don't have it. Taking just part, you'd want: `Dim Client_Save As String, Type_Save As String, Response As String` instead of what you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: **Don't use spaces in your field or table names.**

It is clear that you are in dire need of an improved understanding of Access fundamentals, but for now I'll just concentrate on getting you over your current hurdle.

When you add a field to a form in access with spaces in the field name, Access silently replaces the spaces with underscores.  So the following code should work with your database as it is currently designed:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "UPDATE [Main Details] " & _
"SET [Main Details].[Status] = '" & Status & "' " & _
", [Main Details].[On Hold] = '" & On_Hold & "' " & _
"WHERE   [Main Details].[Account] = '" & Account & "';", dbFailOnError
```

I also changed the `AND` to a comma in your UPDATE statement, replaced `DoCmd.RunSQL` with `CurrentDb.Execute` with the `dbFailOnError` option so that your query won't throw up dialog boxes or fail silently (if you turn off the warnings, as most people do with DoCmd.RunSQL).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Unfortunately, I didn't write the table names myself, and its an old system which I am learning to support.

Comment: Aaaaahhhh!!!! I just saw your updated question with all the `Sleep` and `SendKeys` calls.  You are starting down a dark path my friend.  I'm trying hard not to be too discouraging, but you are setting yourself up for big problems down the road.  Please review some of the material at http://allenbrowne.com/tips.html.  Sooner rather than later would be good.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didnt write the code. Thank you for your advice and the link, it has been invaluable.

Comment: Best of luck, then.  I don't envy you.